# Is there the notion of a partial mapping in category theory?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, category-theory, higher-category-theory

In category theory we are largely concerned with **mappings** between objects. These could be the mappings between the objects within a category (e.g. connections between members of a set that makeup the category) or these could be higher level, such as mappings between categories themselves.

The mapping between objects within a category are **morphisms**, and the mappings between categories are **functors**.

My questions is, can morphisms and functors be *partial*? In other words, could there be a "degraded" morphism between any 2 objects, such that there is "some" connection but it's not as good as it could be.

This would be analogous to a communication channel, with input, channel and output (or source and sink), where the communication is not perfect (say noise in the channel) but the message can still be understood.

Comment: Does this help? https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+function#in_category_theory

Comment: @StiftungWarentest hmm looks promising. I will look into this and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Restriction categories" address your question almost entirely:

- https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/restriction+category
- https://cs.ioc.ee/ewscs/2010/cockett/estonia-slides-3.pdf
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397500003820

Comment: I wonder if "quasi-categories" would also be related. 
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870815001577